# Onepage.php error

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting this error when someone tries to checkout from the shopping cart?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/baskzcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php on line 732

Comment: Hi there, you can check answers & give feedback

Answer (score 0):

It seems your **php** version doesn't support `[]` notation for arrays (**php** version lower than 5.4), you should use `array()` instead to fix the error

A better idea could be upgrading **php** to 5.* (5.4 at least), as once you have fixed the concrete reported error some others could appear if you don't upgrade

More info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29505827/1073040